# Explaining if a SHA1 alternative is a good hash function

Tags: function, hash, sha1

Split the message into 160-bit blocks. Leave the first block unchanged, shift the 2nd block 1 bit left, shift the 3rd block 2 bits left, and so on. The shift wraps bits around, i.e., 1011...00 shifted 2 bits left is 11...0010. Then xor the resulting blocks together to obtain a 160-bit digest.

Is this a good hash function?

Comment: Probably not, no. Sounds like collisions would occur quite easily.

Comment: No, for input less than 20 bytes it can be easily reversed (most passwords are only around 12 characters so around 12 bytes).

Comment: I guess the [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) SE sites would be a better place for this question - and even there it might be really hard to find the very few giving good advice between all the *normal* people - IMO you need a few real experts and quite some time to weight a new crypto relevant algorithm - I think there are only a few people here who could really tell (I am surely none of those) - so tread the answers with care

Answer (score 1):

Do you need [cryptographic strength hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)? Are you planning to use it to:

- Verify integrity of sensitive data (files, transactions, passwords, etc.)
- Identify yourself, your data or your computations
- Use it as part of another cryptographic or verification scheme

If so, use an existing and tested hash function. SHA-1 itself is [regarded as vulnerable](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/10/06/sha1-crypto-algorithm-could-fall-by-2018/) an unsuitable for secure applications and it's way more secure than your algorithm. Almost everyone (myself included) is [dangerously bad at cryptography](http://www.happybearsoftware.com/you-are-dangerously-bad-at-cryptography.html). If you haven't even tested your hash function, or don't know how to test a hash function, you aren't that good at crypto either.

Or can you get away with a normal hash function? Are you just using this for internal computations that don't get saved or stored? Then you might have a need to roll your own hash function. From your default to 160-bit digests and comparison to SHA-1, it doesn't sound like this is your use case. Most non-crypto hash functions roll out power-of-two digest lengths. Again, however, there are other open sourced and [tested hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions) available, so why re-invent the wheel?

If you want to learn, I suggest you implement your hash function in code then put in the effort to test it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392304/how-to-test-a-hash-function) for some primer info on this. There is an open source project called [SMHasher](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/SMHasher) that "is a test suite designed to test the distribution, collision, and performance properties of non-cryptographic hash functions - it aims to be the "DieHarder" of hash testing, and does a pretty good job of finding flaws with a number of popular hashes."

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in alternates of SHA-1 then look in to [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and [SHA-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)

As of now SHA-2 is most secure hashing algorithm. And about SHA-3 Wikipedia says:

> SHA-3 is not meant to replace SHA-2, as no significant attack on SHA-2
>   has been demonstrated